# Child content types

Tags: nodes

I need to create two content types (Call List and Call Announcements), in Call Announcements there are 5 fields, in Call List there are 12 fields but 5 of them are mutual with Call Announcements, I do not want to create 2 different content types (Call List, Call Announcements) because when the user create a node, he should be able to choose where the node is shown (in Call List, in Call Announcements, Both). (Call List and Call Announcements should be in the same database table)

> [image]

How can I do these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and use a taxonomy vocabulary with Call List and Call Announcements as items that users can select on node creation. Of course, add a term reference field to that vocabulary under "manage fields" for the parent content type.

Conditional Fields can hide/disable/show fields upon user choice (Call List or Call Announcements).

Comment: Thanks you, but I am sorry, I did not understand I try to apply your instructions but could not achieve

Comment: a. You should create a content type e.g. named Call b. create a taxonomy vocabulary called for example Call Tags c. for this vocabulary add two terms: Call List & Call Announcements. d. back to content type 'call' add a term reference field to Call Tags Vocab. e. create all other fields under node type Call. f. Install Conditional Fields module and read documentation at project page for further instructions. All the best.